# Include testing test groups for failsafe (integration testing) only but exclude them from surefire

Tags: maven, testing, spring-boot, testng

The following config does not work. No test is in scope for the goal `integration-test`.

In case it is unclear, What should happen is that what I do a `mvn integration-test` the failsafe plugin should run my test. But the surefire plugin configuration is excluding the test. If I uncomment the surefire config block the test is run during the integration-test goal.

Maven config:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <groups>spring-container-sanity</groups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludedGroups>spring-container-sanity</excludedGroups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

A Java Test class

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")
public class SimpleTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Test(groups = "spring-container-sanity")
    public void isHessianServiceExported() throws Exception {
      /*...*/

    }
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". If there's an error please post it. If not, how did you attest that "it did not work"?

Comment: "no test is in scope" ? basic computer science terminology.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the tests are run when surefire is disabled. Failsafe has a file naming convention for integration tests, if the tests you want to run do not follow this they won't be in scope and the `group` rule will have nothing to match. So, in this case to get failsafe to resolve the tests it should run correctly you first need to add an include filter. This build block will work:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <groups>spring-container-sanity</groups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludedGroups>spring-container-sanity</excludedGroups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

When annotating your test, make sure to define an array of groups, even if its only a single one.

`@Test(groups = {"spring-container-sanity"})`